# D3.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, dashboard

I'm trying a tutorial and the domain request isn't loading. The links are working okay, but I'm still getting a error. I'm working on a dashboard in D3.js. I appreciate your help!

```
d3.json("https://oec.world/attr/country/", function(country_error, countries) {
  if (country_error) return console.arn(country_error);
  countries.data.forEach(function(d) {
    country_attrs[d.id] = d;
  });
});

d3.json("https://oec.world/hs/export/2011/show/all/all/", function(error_2011, json_2011) {
  if (error_2011) return console.warn(error_2011);
  json_2011.data.forEach(function(d) {
    data[d.origin_id] = {
      "export_val_2011": d.export_val,
      "id": d.origin_id
    }
  });

  d3.json("https://oec.world/hs/export/2010/show/all/all/", function(error_2010, json_2010) {
    if (error_2010) return console.warn(error_2010);
    json_2010.data.forEach(function(d) {
      if(data[d.origin_id]) {
        data[d.origin_id]["export_val_2010"] = d.export_val
      }
    });
```

Comment: Is there any link to that tutorial? Can you see any error on the console?